# How to suppress/remove PHP session cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, header, http-headers

I need to suppress an already set session cookie header, but I cannot find any way to do this.

<strike>Why?

I need to make an image, sent by a PHP script, cacheable by the end user; this image is used to track if a newsletter has been read by the receiver, so if the image is requested I know the newsletter has been read. I only need to know when the newsletter gets opened for the first time, the subsequent requests can be ignored. The problem is that, even if I properly set the Expire and Cache-Control headers, the image is requested every time the user opens the newsletter--only that image used for the tracking--basically because it's not cached by the user. I used this [tool](http://www.ircache.net/cgi-bin/cacheability.py) to understand why the URL is not cacheable, and it says because of the cookie sent.</strike>

What I want to avoid is the user seeing a delay on the load of the tracking image.

So I have a `session_start()` in my website init function, that I don't want to remove, because the website is big and complicated, and making some radical change like starting the session only if needed (one of the solutions I envisioned) is not desirable. Calling `session_start()` sets the `Set-Cookie:` header with the `PHPSESSID` cookie, and I need to remove it. Reading from the `header()` page on php.net I tried setting it with an empty value like this

```
header('Set-Cookie:');
header('Set-Cookie:', true);
header('Set-Cookie: ');
header('Set-Cookie: ', true);
```

before and after a call to `session_write_close()`, but all I obtained is that the user receives a `Set-Cookie:` header, without any value, exactly as written in the `header` function argument.

I must say I'm still using PHP 5.2, so I cannot use the `header_remove()` function I see in the manual, and lighttpd 1.4.24.

**EDIT:** so, it seems the tool I used to check my headers is not that good. I looked at the headers with `curl --head` and saw the headers below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=qn3ms55nvst2717e7b73qqu445; path=/
Last-Modified: Sun, 29 Mar 2009 21:53:36 GMT
ETag: "cb1dffff8c10db7b0a88794b1453cab8"
Expires: Sun, 20 Dec 2009 23:28:07 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 1322
Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2009 23:28:07 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.24
```

As you see it is set a `Pragma: no-cache`. The tool I used said that the `Pragma` header is not used, but it was wrong. I tried setting `Pragma: cache`, and it made the mail client cache the image.

I made another discovery, maybe the impossibility of unsetting the `Set-Cookie` header is because of lighttpd, since I cannot remove the `Pragma` header using `header('Pragma:')`. Looking forward to PHP 5.3. Can someone using Apache confirm that the above `header` call removes the `Pragma` header?

Thanks txyoji for the enlightening comment :-)

At this point it seems this question is here only to confirm lighttpd cannot remove headers by setting an header without value.

Comment: Can you show a complete list of headers sent in response to the dynamic image request. This tool will show a complete list of headers. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829

Comment: A nice tool that analyses your headers is http://redbot.org/. It can help figure out why a response it not being cached.

Answer (score 2):

try `header_remove('Set-Cookie');`

Comment: This worked for me, but it looked at first like it didn't because it silently failed if the headers were already set. The solution was to enable output buffering.

The other answers all seem to either have no effect, send blank Set-Cookie headers or send already expired cookies but that's not useful if you want to suppress it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

From [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> In order to kill the session
>   altogether, like to log the user out,
>   the session id must also be unset. If
>   a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then
>   the session cookie must be deleted.
>   setcookie() may be used for that.

Does this code work?

```
setcookie("PHPSESSID", 'foo', time()-3600);  /* expired 1 hour ago */
```

Another solution would be to serve the image through a PHP file, so whenever it gets requested, you can update your database and set a flag to your subscriber table that the newsletter was opened. Much cleaner solution IMHO. You would embed the image with code like this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/tracker.php?idhash=1234234"/>
```

where idhash could be a combination of subscriber ID plus newsletter ID.

Comment: I don't need to end the session, because it is started but doesn't contain anything, and I don't need to remove the cookie from the user's browser, because it has not been set yet. What I need is to avoid PHP sending the `Set-Cookie:` header at all.
Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Another note, I'm already serving the image exactly like you suggest in the second part.

Comment: Hmm, does session_cache_limiter help anything or maybe setting Caching directives via header() for the image with the serving file?

Comment: bit of a nitpick, but `setcookie(session_name(), ...` is probably a slightly better way to reference the cookie, since session name can be overridden.

Comment: @Frank True, though the header shown in the question shows it's PHPSESSID in this case. But you are definitely right. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase the length of the sessions so they don't expire when the user closes thier browser? Set a session variable on the first time the image is loaded by the user. This way it doesn't matter if the image was requested multiple times. You only update the db when the variable isn't set.

Comment: My problem is not reducing the number of db updates, I want to avoid the user waiting for the image to load (because of the inevitable delay of the request) from the second view of the newsletter. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the image is requested because of the session cookie, and not simply because the E-Mail client for some reason doesn't do any caching?

Comment: Well, I really don't know if this is the case, but I have strong clues that suggest the client is actually caching: I see in my newsletter that only the image used for tracking is delayed, all of the others are instantly shown as I open the mail, and similar behavior on other newsletters. I'm even not sure the session cookie is the cause of the problem, but I think I want to try, and if this doesn't work, this might be a problem interesting to tackle on its own. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

How about conditionally changing the session cookie name with session_name() depending on the url that's requested?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point on doing this. Can you explain better? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header('Pragma:',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not send a set cookie header the first time that you start your session.

PHP will set the pragma: nocache header if your session_cache_limiter() is set to 'private' when the session is started. If allowing the cache is all you want, call

```
session_cache_limiter('public')
```

before you call session_start(). It must be before session_start(), which means that if your php environment is set to autostart the session, then you have to set session.cache_limiter = public in your php.ini.

If PHP is sending the set cookie header, then one of four things is happening.

**1) The session is being started multiple times.**

---

no source - but a one-line PHP program will verify this for you.

---

```
session_start();        //  <-- cookie is not sent
session_start();        //  <-- does not count as a second start, nothing happens

session_start();        //  <-- cookie is not sent
session_write_close();  // session_destroy() counts as well
session_start();        //  <-- cookie is sent, since the session has been closed
```

Check your request and response headers. If the phpsessid value is the same in the response as it is in the request, then this probably is what is happening.

**2) The session is being regenerated after it is started**

---

[PHP.NET - session_regenerate_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) - Changelog for 4.3.3

---

```
session_regenerate_id();
```

Check your request and response headers. If they are different, then this is probably what is happening.

**3) The sessionid is being set prior to the session being started**

---

[PHP.NET - session_id](http://php.net/session_id) - Parameters

---

```
session_id('whatever');
session_start();
```

This one is easy to check for. If you see a call to session_id anywhere in your code, then it's either: before a call to session_start, and is the problem; or it's after a call to session_start, and it does nothing.

**4) setcookie( session_name() , ... , ... ) is being called, setting the cookie manually somewhere**

---

No Source

---

```
setcookie(session_name(),'a session id')
// or setcookie('PHPSESSID', 'a session id')
```

This one is also easy to check for. Look for any instances of setcookie.

Answer (score 0):

your question isnt really clear, but if you want to remove the PHP session cookie completely (on log-out for example), you can use

```
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', 0, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], isset($params['httponly']));
```